# Как работать с окнами (формы)?

Tags: c#

Как работать с окнами (формы) в C#? Открывать новое окно, но чтобы старое было все равно открыто, или чтобы старое закрывалось. Задавать ширину окна, высоту и всякое другое =)

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```
// Какой-то обработчик
private void buttonOldForm_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // Прячем текущую форму (если надо)
    this.Hide();

    // Создаем и показываем новую форму
    NewForm f = new NewForm();
    f.InstanceRef = this;
    f.Show();
}
```

А для перемещения использовать свойство Location (и подобные):

```
f.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Странный вопрос. Я вот так даже с ходу не припомню примеров программ, где закрывается основная форма программы, когда открывается новая. 
Если вы показываете пользователю, например, опции приложения, то основное окно однозначно должно остаться. Если же хотите отобразить какой-то новый функционал приложения, то лучше это делать в этом же окне, используя что-то вроде вкладок.